# What is the syntax for excluding files with a certain extension using Bamboo SCP task?

Tags: ant, bamboo

[image: SCP task]

I want to copy all local files except the coffeescript files. I've tried using Ant syntax but I think that only works for include, not exclude or regex. I've tried with a unix glob as well, which works in Bash but fails in Bamboo:

`for f in **/*.!(coffee); do echo "Processing $f file.."; done`

What is the syntax for excluding files by extension in Bamboo's SCP task?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your actual requirement is, but if you don't need coffee pattern files, you can exclude them while checkout itself.

Comment: I know I can work around this but I want to know if there's a way to just exclude them via the Bamboo step -- because it seems like a normal thing to want to do.

Comment: Did you find a way? @jcollum

Comment: No. I ended up writing a bash script to do tar up the files I needed then untar them on the other end. That's what I would recommend, but it's not a valid answer to the question.